# Rotating an Scaling a UIBezierPath on Autorotate

Tags: ios, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I'm working on a simple drawing View. For this I add CAShapeLayers with a UIBezierpath to a UIView. My problem is, that on rotation the drawings will not resize.  Instead it goes out of bounds.

Basically I try to imitate the behavior of the photo-app where have an image in portrait filling the whole screen and on rotation, it will scale it corresponding to landscape without changing the aspect ration.

I found solutions here which do the rotation at the same position, but I can't find anywhere how to do the scaling.

Thanks

Comment: You can do this with a single UIImageView set to the bounds of the screen. Then set the content mode to ScaleAspectFit. This will then resize the image on rotation.

Comment: Hm maybe I described it wrong. I don't have an image. Instead I have some free handdrawings created via CAShapedLayer with UIBezierpath. I just want the scaling. So e.g. if I draw on top of an image and then rotate the device, the drawing is still at the same spot on top of the image.

Comment: You need to scale the position of the layer along with the scale of the image you have drawn it over.

Comment: Just scale the control points and start/end points of your UIBezierPath and the curve will be scaled accordingly.

Comment: @fang do you kniw where to get the transform from? On autorotate my imagevie is automatically rotated and scaled.